# CacheResponseStatus enums confuses me a bit

Tags: java, caching, httpclient

Anyone can explain why **CacheResponseStatus** defines these two Values?

```
CACHE_HIT  A response was generated from the cache with no requests sent upstream.

CACHE_MODULE_RESPONSE The response was generated directly by the caching module.
```

For me both are equal as the Cache delivers the response.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient-cache/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/cache/CacheResponseStatus.html